# CheckBox Node renderer

Tags: java, swing

I have a situation where i need to implement a custom tree cell renderer.
   My specification is to have only a checkbox node and text for the parent node and not the        folder icon that is used in the default tree cell renderer.

I achieved it through the following code snippet.

```
public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
        boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row,
        boolean hasFocus) {


    JLabel l = (JLabel)renderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent(
            tree, "", true, expanded, leaf, row, true);


    l.setIcon(null);
    l.setText(value.toString());
        panel.removeAll();
        panel.add(this, BorderLayout.WEST);
        panel.add(l);
        return panel;

}
```

The screen shot of the result is like this .
[image: Parent Node Output]

Now you can see the grey area enclosing the text "One" .

Can you guide me as to clear the grey area ?

The output must look something that does not have the grey around the text.

:)

Comment: The grey color probably comes from your panel. Try calling `panel.setOpaque( false );`

Comment: @Robin . setOpaque does not work here . Tried it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this issue is there very simple workaround to `setBackground` in `TreeCellRenderer` with `Color` that returns

```
Color clr = UIManager.getColor("Tree.textForeground");
```

[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971478/check-box-node-tree-custom-renderer-in-swing) from yesterday included

Comment: Do you mean                 renderer.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Tree.textForeground"));

Comment: @Achilles please not, ever Renderer returns Component, btw are you tried code example that I posted yesterday, check variables `textForeground = UIManager.getColor("Tree.textForeground");` and `textBackground = UIManager.getColor("Tree.textBackground");`
 for their usage in the `TreeCellRenderer`, sure I understand your problems --> one year (1 and 1/2) back I had same IceHockey with lots of Swing Methods :-)

Comment: I tried the approach that you suggested .But it seems to be not working . If you notice the above code , i use a label and put the text inside the label and in turn put the label inside a panel . Any suggestions ?